# A question about invertible matrices, $A,B$ are invertible matrices, $AB+BA=0$, show that n is even

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ be invertible matrices, and let $AB+BA=0$, show that n is even.

I know what the solution is: $AB=-BA\Rightarrow |1|=(-1)^n|1|\Rightarrow \text{n is even}$.

So we know that every invertible matrix say $C$ has only one matrix say $D$ such that, $CD=DC=I$, but in this question it doesn't say if $A$ and $B$ are such matrices that they are  unique one to each other, so why can we assume that $AB=BA=I$ ?

Comment: But we haven't assumed that $AB = BA = I$.

Comment: @M.Vinay if not then why $AB=I$?

Comment: Where does it say $AB = I$?

Comment: @M.Vinay, I saw egreg answer now. I see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write your relation
$$
ABA^{-1}=-B
$$
you get that 
$$\det B=\det(-B).$$
Now, what can you say about $\det(aB)$, where $a$ is a scalar?

Comment: Thanks. Is there commutativity here $ABA^{-1}=B$ ?

Comment: @GinKin From $AB=-BA$, you get $ABA^{-1}=-BAA^{-1}$, multiplying by $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Yeah I got that, then you're left with $ABA^{-1}=-B$ so how do you cancel out the $A$ and $A^{-1}$ around the $B$ on the LHS, i.e $ABA^{-1}$ to get to the next step ?

Comment: @GinKin I *don't* cancel $A$ and $A^{-1}$ around $B$. Rather, I notice that $-BAA^{-1}=-BI=-B$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the fact that $$\det(\alpha\cdot A)=\alpha^n\cdot\det(A)$$ for a scalar $\alpha\in F$ and $A\in M_n(F)$.

So you have $$\det(AB)=\det(-BA)=(-1)^n\det(BA)$$ but since $\det(BA)=\det(AB)$ you get
$$\det(AB)=(-1)^n\det(AB)$$
hence $(-1)^n=1$ and thus $n$ must be even.

Answer (score 0):

We have :
\begin{align*}
& AB+BA=0 \implies AB=-BA \\
& \implies det(AB)=det(-BA)=(-1)^n det(BA)=(-1)^n det(AB)\\
\end{align*}
We know that $A, B \in GL_n(\mathbb K)$.
Then, $AB, BA \in GL_n(\mathbb K)$. 
As a reult, $det(AB), det(BA) \ne 0$.
Finally, $(-1)^n=1$